# Как отсортировать столбцы независимо друг от друга?

Tags: python, pandas, сортировка, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('random.xlsx')
df.sort_values(['Name','Birthday','City of birth','Favorite color of the rainbow', 'Favorite subject at school'], ascending = [True])
df
```

Проблема в том, что сортирует только первый столбец, а надо чтобы все.

[image: Ексель файл]

Добавил фотку таблицы. Надо чтобы каждый столбец сортировался отдельно.
К примеру, столбец с именами сортировался по алфавиту, столбец 2 по дате, столбец 3 по алфавиту, столбец 4 и 5 также по алфавиту.

Comment: В смысле вы хотите сортировать столбцы независимо друг от друга? Эта сортировка сортирует, но как и в `SQL` по очереди, второй столбец сортируется внутри одинаковых значений первого столбца и т.д.

Comment: В общем, уточните вопрос - покажите как выглядят ваши данные, что вы получаете и что вам хотелось бы получить.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос желаемый результат, который должен получиться из приведенного примера таблицы

Comment: Спасибо помогло, можем закрывать вопрос(я сам хз как)

Comment: Пожалуйста, никода не приводите данные картинками, только текстом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий пример:

```
In [124]: np.random.seed(42)

In [125]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(5, 3)), columns=list("abc"))

In [126]: df
Out[126]:
    a   b   c
0   6  19  14
1  10   7   6
2  18  10  10
3   3   7   2
4   1  11   5

In [127]: res = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=0), columns=df.columns)

In [128]: res
Out[128]:
    a   b   c
0   1   7   2
1   3   7   5
2   6  10   6
3  10  11  10
4  18  19  14
```

**NOTE:** учтите, при такой сортировке у вас разрываются связи в строках, т.е. все столбцы будут отсортированы **независимо друг от друга**. То что до сортировки принадлежало одной строке, после сортировки может быть разбросано по разным строкам. Только так можно реализовать то, что вы описали в вопросе.